# How do you earn prestige in Darkville?

Tags: darkville

Besides having to pay for it or complete missions :)

After you complete the game, you can still fight people and buy stuff. But you can't earn prestige because there are no more missions to complete. So you can only buy things that can be bought with $, which are worthless...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't earn prestige after all of the missions are completed, that is the only way to earn prestige in Darkville without purchasing prestige with real cash or "Q Points".

Hope this helps!